# Saas deployment architecture

Tags: kubernetes, deployment, architecture, containers, saas

I’m currently developing a web application and I was wondering how I will deploy it for the customers.
Here all the options I was thinking about.

1- I was thinking about Docker/Kubernetes. Each customer has a container with the app and database.

2- Each customer has a container but the database will be in a separate storage global to all customers.

3- Or everyone accessing the web app to the same container and I will create more container with time and kubernetes will manage the load balancing between them. The database will be global to all customers.

The third option will be easier to scale/manage and update.

Thanks for your knowledge about this subject ! I will gladly take all the informations about this topic.

For now I just have multiple container with docker and load balancing with kubernetes. Each customer has its own database.

Comment: While you obviously need to be very careful about keeping customers' data separated in the shared database, having just one copy of the application makes it much easier to update the application and to onboard new customers.  If each customer has their own container and you have 1,000 customers, how will you roll out a routine code update?

Answer (score 0):

AWS offers good documentation to get started here : https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/apn/building-a-multi-tenant-saas-solution-using-aws-serverless-services/

My brief understanding:

- (3) for simple SAAS and especially MVP keep all tenants on 1 server
  and in 1 database. Just make the application SOLID, so you can later
  change the implementation.  As the application grows, you can
  introduce separate servers/containers for DB, Caching, File Server,
  etc. Even split Tenants on separate containers.
- (1) for big application with the high risk in case if 1 tenant will
  see/change the data of another tenant -- separate containers.
  Especially if customer will need the right to migrate to self-hosted
  application.
- For (2)nd variant, I rather use views populated tenant's database:

  ```
  CREATE VIEW `CommonDatabase`.`example` AS SELECT * FROM `Tenant1Database`.`TableName`;
  ```